# Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Server is in single user mode. Only one administrator can connect at this time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have installed SQL Server in ubuntu20 and started it using command

```
sudo -u mssql /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr -f
```

Then I tried connecting to the same using dbvisualizer client, which is installed on windows.

I'm able to establish the connection. But, when i try to execute some command `select * from mytable`. It gives me error saying

> An error occurred while establishing the connection:  Long Message: Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Server is in single user mode. Only one administrator can connect at this time.   ClientConnectionId:b6a79d5b-713f-46aa-9268-f5dc0ab672bc  Details:    Type: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException    Error Code: 18461    SQL State: S0001 "

Comment: The error is telling you the problem, the instance is in single user mode, and thus you've already used up the single connection. Take the instance out of single user mode, restart it, and then connect.

Comment: can you help me how can i do that? or please share the resource to read.

Comment: In your start-up you have specifically stated you wanted single user mode, @Devan, by supplying the `-f` switch... Have a read of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/database-engine-service-startup-options?view=sql-server-ver15#other-startup-options).

Comment: Yeah, Got it. thank you @Larnu

Answer (score 1):

As @Larnu pointed out in their comment, the `-f` switch is the cause of your single-user mode startup.
The Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/database-engine-service-startup-options?view=sql-server-ver15#other-startup-options) indicates that `-f` starts the instance with a minimal configuration, which is inherently single-user mode.

To correct this, stop the instance using `sudo systemctl stop msssql-server`

Then, start a new instance in multi-user mode with `sudo -u mssql /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr`